# Java NullPointerException after reading from database

Tags: java

This code throws me a NullPointerException

```
int StrtYr = getYear(timeToDate(0));
int YrDiff = 0;
int Pyr = 0;
List <Tuple> FP_entry = selectFrom(dummy_prices).list();
for (Tuple row : FP_entry){
    Pyr = row.get(dummy_prices.year);
    YrDiff = Pyr - StrtYr;
    if (YrDiff >= 0) {
        create_FPrice_tm(YrDiff, row.get(dummy_prices.price));
        }
    }
```

"dummy_prices" is a database table that contains two fields (int year, double price)

"FPrice_tm" is an instance of a dynamic event. it's defined for the simulation model.

Comment: Debug the code and see what is null and put check accordingly.

Comment: My guess is that `FP_entry` is coming back `null` and then you're trying to iterate it.

Comment: but why would FP_entry come back null?